# DataBinding ObserableField<String> not updating the view

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I've gone through many post related to the data-binding but didn't find the solution for my problem. I've created a sample app to learn the data binding.

**Expected Behaviour**: I've a edittext and textview. The textview should get updated with whatever I write in the edittext.

**Problem:** I've created a Observable and link it to both edittext and textview. While writing inside the edittext, my textview is not updating. I'm doing something wrong here. Please check the code below-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMainBinding.setStudent(new Student("Rahul"));
        activityMainBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="student"
            type="com.rahulchaurasia.databindingtest.Student"/>
    </data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.rahulchaurasia.databindingtest.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@{student.name}"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{student.name}"/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {
    public ObservableField<String> name;

    public Student(String n) {
       name = new ObservableField<>(n);
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: @Emil Hi, it should work without getName() method because I've seen in other post that getters/setters are not required if we use ObservableFields. Even it is not working after adding getName() though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binding of the `EditText` should be bidirectional `@={student.name}`.